# Checkbox in Jtable with Dialog

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jtable, jcheckbox

Q: I have implemented jtable with checkbox in it now when user click on particular checkbox dialog gets opened where user can add more information to the selected item 
now if user does click close button in dialog then i need to uncheck the selected item from jtable ?

Note :**i am opening dialog through setValueAt method of class which extends AbstractTableModel?**

```
How can i workaround this problem?
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: To uncheck checkbox call `setValueAt` again.

Comment: Add a mouse listener to the table. Open the dialog when the correct column is clicked

Comment: Don't use the model, add an TableCellEditor to your column.

Answer (score 1):

> I have implemented jtable with checkbox in it now when user click on particular checkbox dialog gets opened

Instead of using a check box you can use a JButton as a renderer. Then when you click on the button the dialog will display. Then you don't need to worry about resetting the checkbox.

See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for more information.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. My problem has been solved i tried to pass the reference of the class which extends  AbstractTableModel to the dialog and performed the functionality on the closeDialog() method.